# Is there a way to get an NSSet of all of the touches on the screen with SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Is there a way that I can have something inside didSimulatePhysics that gets a list of all the touches currently on the screen?

Comment: implement the touches events in a subclass of SKView or directly in the viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

In the `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, and `touchesEnded`, you could just cache them each in an `NSMutableDictionary` class property or ivar and then use them as needed in didSimulatePhysics.

for example :

```
// in YourScene.h
NSMutableDictionary *touchCache;

// in YourScene.m
touchCache = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];


// in your touchesBegan
[touchCache setObject:touches forKey@"touchesBegan"];


// in your touchesMoved
[touchCache setObject:touches forKey@"touchesMoved"];


// in your touchesEnded
[touchCache setObject:touches forKey@"touchesEnded"];
```

Then, in `didSimulatePhysics` you can access the last NSSet containing touches via that ivar or class property.

Although, keep in mind you should be maintaining those caches when a touch ends, etc. This is just a conceptual example of an approach you could take.

Comment: If I did this, even when there were no touches on the screen, wouldn't there still be some? The list of touches that touchesEnded provides are the ones on the screen before they are ended.

Comment: "Although, keep in mind you should be maintaining those caches when a touch ends, etc. This is just a conceptual example of an approach you could take." - directly from my answer.

Comment: If a touch has begun.... and has not ended, it's active. Right ? That's the maintaining I spoke of. When a touch ends, you need to purge the touchBegan and touchMoved caches of those touches.